# How to query for a built string select

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to do something like

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ('reword#' || reword) || reword_faq as reword FROM me_review_entries re
) as re
WHERE re.reword = 'reword#2#SOME_FAQ'
```

I tried to do

```
SELECT ('reword#' || reword) || reword_faq as foo FROM me_review_entries re
WHERE foo = 'reword#2#SOME_FAQ'
```

But I get:

```
ERROR:  column "foo" does not exist
LINE 2: WHERE foo = 'reword#2#SOME_FAQ'
```

Is the first way of doing the only way ? Or could I improve that ?

Comment: You can use column aliases on ORDER BY statement's but not at WHERE because WHERE is executed before SELECT

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it depends on your database, but the foo column does not exist except within the query, so you might have to do:

```
SELECT ('reword#' || reword) || reword_faq as foo FROM me_review_entries re
WHERE ('reword#' || reword) || reword_faq = 'reword#2#SOME_FAQ'
```